# how to find least significant byte of an integer in Java?

Tags: bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I need help with the following problem:

Write an expression that results in the least significant byte of an integer x being set to 0, but all other bits unchanged.
For example: 0x98234493 becomes 0x98234400.

I am confused on how to access the least significant byte.

```
public static int Q3(int x) {
    return (x & 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please add a language tag to represent which language you are using. Hex is base 32 - `F` represents 15 in base 10 (our number system) and `1111` in base 2 (binary), so `FFFFFFFF` represents 4*8 bits (40 bits), when really you only want the rightmost 8 bits. Think you're looking for `0xff`, not `0xffffffff`. May wanna read up on working with different bases.

Comment: No offence but I think you can give it more of a try. You're not resetting *any* bits, not even the wrong bits.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the least significant byte of an integer (as your question is stated),
then it's very simple:

`byte b = (byte) (x & 0xFF);`

This works because all the high bits of `0xFF` will be set to 0 by default, so you are masking out everything but the bottom byte. A byte is 8 bits and each 'F' is 4 bits (written in hexadecimal). In binary, an F is 1111, so FF masks out everything but the bottom 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
public static int Q3(int x) {
    return (x & ~255);
}
```

255 in binary would have all the bits in the least significant byte set while all others are zero.

Therefore ~255, which is the complement of 255, will have all bits except those in the least significant byte set while all bits of the least significant byte are zeros.

This ~255 can be `&`ed with the input number `n` to set all bits in the least significant byte to zero while the other bits remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The solution will be

```
public static int Q3(int x) {
    return (x & OxF);
}
```

Comment: This would give you the least significant last four bits, not the least significant byte.